# How to remove duplicates from a StringCollection in c#?

Tags: c#, collections

How to remove duplicates from a StringCollection in c#? I was looking for a more efficient approach. StringCollection is returned from an API.

Comment: A more efficient approach than what?

Comment: Actually what I had in mind was to traverse every entity and remove all instances except one. But now I have found one statement solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) as your collection, rather than `StringCollection`. It is designed to prevent the addition of duplicate elements by comparing hash codes of those elements (thus being very efficient).

Edit: Since it would *seem* you're returned a `StringCollection` in the first place, then the solution should just be to loop over all the items in the `StringCollection` and add them to a `HashSet<string>`, thereby eliminating duplicates. The [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) extension method would also do the job, but less efficiently I suspect, since it does use hashing (rather just normal equality testing). Something like this:

```
var noDuplicatesItems = stringCollection.Cast<string>().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: The OP did say the StringCollection was coming from an API.

Comment: @Rowland: Thanks, but really worth the down-vote? My answer still largely applies.

Comment: Good solution but... he could use it only with the framework 3.5 or above.

Comment: @Claudio: Yes, true... however with .NET 4.0 out now, it is likely most people are at least using .NET 3.5 for new programs. It wouldn't be too hard to implement your own `HashSet<T>` also.

Comment: @Noldorin `StringCollection` doesn't appear to support `IEnumerable<string>`, so `Enumerable.Distinct()` wouldn't be available?

Comment: @Rowland: It supports `IEnumerable`. So `Cast<string>().Distinct()` will work.

Comment: @Rowland: See my response on the other post.

Comment: I have used 
`HashSet<string> tt = new HashSet<string>(possibleEntities.Cast<string>().ToList() );`
How Should I convert back to StringCollection?

Comment: @Rowland: It wasn't there when I wrote mine either. :)

Comment: @Taz: Do you really need to convert back to `StringCollection`? If so, simply initialise a new instance and call `newStringCollection.AddRange(tt)`.

Comment: @Noldorin Thanks. Actually I have already written some code and then realized I need to remove duplicates. So that is why I have to convert back.

Comment: @Noldorin Actually it works like this `newStringCollection.AddRange(tt.Cast<string>().ToArray());`

Comment: @Tax: Ah, glad it's solved. I'm pretty sure you don't need the `ToArray()` call still (that just adds an extra iteration over the collection), but whatever does the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
    StringCollection s = new StringCollection();
    s.Add("s");
    s.Add("s");
    s.Add("t");

    var uniques = s.Cast<IEnumerable>();
    var unique = uniques.Distinct();

    foreach (var x in unique)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.Read();
```

Not tested for efficiency.

Comment: Does the job, though I'm not a fan of the lack of generics here.

Comment: Try compiling it and running it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in v3.5 of the Framework (or later), then you can first convert to an `IEnumerable<string>`, and then call the `Distinct()` method on that; ie:

```
// where foo is your .Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
IEnumerable<string> distinctList = foo.OfType<string>.Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

using linq: `myCollection.Cast<string>.Distinct().ToList();`
or you can use a HashSet as Noldorin proposed

Comment: No, because it's not generic. A simple `Cast<string>` will convert it into a generic `IEnumerable<string>` however, then you can use whatever you wish.